# Installing Ubuntu GRUB directly from Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I had windows 8 and Ubuntu side by side managed by Ubuntu GRUB menu. I installed Open Suse, and now Open suse is managing all my operating systems.

I want to remove Open Suse, I don't have Ubuntu Live CD with me.

I'm able to boot into Ubuntu through the open suse grub menu, is it possible to get back Ubuntu GRUB from Ubuntu directly and not from Ubuntu live CD.

What steps should be followed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use the boot repair tool to re-write the MBR for ubuntu 
http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

1. Boot Ubuntu.
2. Run Gparted and delete or format the OpenSuse partition.
3. Open a terminal and run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

That should do the trick.

Comment: This didn't work, it actually crashed my system. The laptop had booted into Open Suse boot manager again and complained of missing operating system@

Comment: Sorry, corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

You must replace **sda** by the hard drive that you use to boot operating systems (without partition number).

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And that's all!